# JSF java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

can someone help me figure out the problem i'm new on JSF. whenever i load my page and submit my form i get this error : 
here is my code :

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class CommandeController extends JSFActions {

    final  static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( CommandeController.class );

    @ManagedProperty( value = "#{commandeBean}")
    private CommandeBean commandeBean;
    @ManagedProperty( value = "#{clientBean}")
    private ClientBean clientBean;
    @ManagedProperty( value = "#{etablissementBean}")
    private EtablissementBean etablissementBean;
    @ManagedProperty( value = "#{commandeFacade}")
    private ICommandeFacade commandeFacade;
```

and my xhtml file look like

```
<h:outputText value="#{lbl.postRef}"  />

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{commandeBean.idPoste}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Choisissez le poste" itemValue="-1"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{jFActions.postes.entrySet()}" var="post"
        itemValue="#{post.key}" itemLabel="#{post.value}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputText value="#{lbl.langUse}"  />

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{commandeBean.langUtilise}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choisissez la langue" itemValue="-1"/>
   <f:selectItem  itemValue="ar" itemLabel="Arabe"/>
   <f:selectItem  itemValue="en" itemLabel="Enlish"/>
   <f:selectItem  itemValue="fr" itemLabel="Frensh"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputText value="#{lbl.nbJ}"  />

<p:inputText id="txtNbrJour" value="#{commandeBean.nbJour}" converterMessage="#{msg.nbrInvalid}" >
    <f:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true" />
</p:inputText>

<h:outputText value="#{lbl.nbjMax}" />
<p:inputText id="txtNJAut" value="#{etablissementBean.nbJourAutorise}"  readonly="true" />
```

---

```
ATTENTION: Erreur inattendue lors du traitement du bean géré «commandeController»
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanPreProcessingException: Erreur inattendue lors du traitement du bean géré «commandeController»
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.preProcessBean(BeanManager.java:398)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:259)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanPreProcessingException: Erreur inattendue lors du traitement de la propriété gérée «commandeBean»
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bake(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.preProcessBean(BeanManager.java:353)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number commandeBean
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1339)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:458)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:350)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:811)
    at com.sun.faces.util.MessageUtils.getExceptionMessageString(MessageUtils.java:398)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.validateLifespan(BeanBuilder.java:574)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.<init>(BeanBuilder.java:523)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bakeBeanProperty(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bake(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:107)
    ... 36 more
18 févr. 2014 10:48:37 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/sgrp-web] threw exception [Erreur inattendue lors du traitement du bean géré «commandeController»] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number commandeBean
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1339)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:458)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:350)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:811)
    at com.sun.faces.util.MessageUtils.getExceptionMessageString(MessageUtils.java:398)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.validateLifespan(BeanBuilder.java:574)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.<init>(BeanBuilder.java:523)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bakeBeanProperty(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.bake(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.preProcessBean(BeanManager.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:259)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at
```

any help ??

Comment: Without looking too hard: your injected properties are beans scoped at a more narrow level than the application bean? What are you trying to achieve by putting that stuff into the application scope? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941

Comment: i put applicationScope to manage all things about commande . thanks for information. now all the beans are injected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `NumberConverter` to convert an object. Use a custom converter instead.

Comment: thanks it worked. but i thought i was converting a field of an object by putting the #{object.field}.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening because I was logging the JSON `{"":{}}` output and that why system generating this exception. JSON was treating like a string in `LogDebug` method.

Use `vlogDebug("my log {0}",jsonObject)`. It will work as it is now in argument `{0}`.